# Can not import module search from google module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I installed the google module by Mario Vilas in my virtual environment in ubuntu 14.04 with python2.7
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google
I have done this before in both windows and Ubuntu and it worked fine.
However, now when I do the following

```
>>> from google import search
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name search
```

I am using pycharm and I can view the package and its modules and I can auto insert using ctrl+space

I tried giving total privileges to the virtual venv package using `sudo chmod -R ugo+rX` but to no avail

[image]

Comment: Do you perhaps have a file named `google.py` in the current directory?

Comment: No, even if I did, the pycharm clicking option should point me to the wrong file. It does not

Comment: Check for circular dependancies, in your import statements.

Comment: Try this: `import google; print google.__file__` to see if you're getting the correct module.

Comment: @aquil.abdullah I tried `import google; google.search('blah')` still get an error

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  All importable modules should have that attribute.  You used `__file__` and not `file`, yes?

Comment: I tried it with `sys` and it gives the same behavior, so I stand corrected.

Comment: Try this: `print google`

Comment: @JohnGordon `<module 'google' (built-in)>`

Comment: @JohnGordon I uninstalled google but I can still import

Comment: It sounds like your installation of Python came with a built-in module named `google` which is taking precedence over the one you installed.  Try renaming your installed version to something else and see if you can import it that way.

Comment: @JohnGordon Something called protobuf. What do I do now?

Comment: @JohnGordon Removed protobuf. I did not need it anyway. Do not understand the purpose. Thanks though. Why not answer formally? I will upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your installation of Python came with a built-in module named `google` which is taking precedence over the one you installed.  You have two options:

1. Remove the built-in module.
2. Use `importlib` to import the desired module by its filesystem path:

   `google = importlib.import_module('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/__init__.py')`

Answer (score 4):

The shortest work around for this will be:

```
from googlesearch import search
```

Answer (score 2):

"from google import search" is giving error as there is no module with the name "google".After "pip install google" i checked the path to find out out the module in lib, but i was not able to find. I checked and found a module with "googlesearch". By doing the below change in my code i was able to solve the issue

OLD : "from google import search"
NEW : "from googlesearch import search"

Comment: The module has been modified and the issue was resolved already. Your answer adds no value, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

simply install both google and google-search

pip install google
pip install google-search

It works for me

Answer (score -1):

Just import google and you will be all set :)

`import google`

It is tested and verified.

Answer (score -4):

I have gone through the same problem and i solve it by importing googlesearch API like this:
from googlesearch import *